Can you ever use the fast travel points in Northwood?
The worldmap of FF7 Rebirth is divided into 8 different regions, each with different places of interest that get fast travel points, which you can click on the map screen to be teleported to that place. The last of those regions is Northwood, which is the setting for the game's final 2 chapters. If I understand correctly during all parts of these 2 chapters fast travel is unavailable, so you can't teleport to any point on any map. However there are still 2 fast travel points on this northern continent, that appear while you play these chapters. One at the Temple of the Ancients, the setting for chapter 13 and one for the Sleeping Forest, where you start chapter 14.


Is there any point in the game where you can teleport to any of these two fast travel points or are they completely useless? I assume those will be usable in the next game of the trilogy, but why are they here in Rebirth, if they are never usable? Perhaps I just missed something and there is indeed a point at which you can use these points to travel to these places.
Note that the fast travel point below the Temple of the Ancients at the southern coast of the continent called "Northwood Port" is actually usable. You can use it to travel to the pier at which you enter the continent from the Tiny Bronco, which is also the game's Point of No Return.
